# Min of 1 character after a certain character in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to record only the details of an email if there is an "@" sign present followed by a minimum of 1 character.

Eg;

**Approved:**

test@gmail.com

test@gmai

test@g

**Disapproved**

test@

test

So, basically I want to first detect if an "@" sign is present followed by atleast a minimum of 1 character.

**What I've tried:**

```
if(strpos($dataEmail, "@") == true) {
  // Send email
}
```

So what this does is to detect if an "@" sign is present in my `$dataEmail` variable.

But how do I go about making sure it has atleast a min of 1 character after the "@" sign?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info: `preg_match('/@./', $dataEmail)`

Comment: How about `if(strpos($dataEmail, "@") < strlen($dataEmail)-1)` ? Sidenote: this is probably the worst way to validate an email

Comment: Note that you may be reinventing a wheel here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Comment: ^--- A [square wheel](https://exceptionnotfound.net/reinventing-the-square-wheel-the-daily-software-anti-pattern/) in fact

Comment: I didn't use the php validation of an email because I didn't want the dot. For my this task, I needed to capture anything that has an @ sign followed by atleast a min of 1 character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode by `@` sign and validate second part (1 index) however you want.

```
<?php

$dataEmail = 'test@';
$explodedEmail = explode('@', $dataEmail);
if (array_key_exists(1, $explodedEmail) && strlen($explodedEmail[1]) > 0) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

but, if you need to validate an email, just use [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php)

Comment: @Cid, added description and recommendation to use php filter function.